# How to enable vscode protocol for Visual Studio extension in Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin

I just installed `Visual Studio` in MacOS Sierra for using `Xamarin`.

And to enable Emacs keybinding in `Visual Studio` I tried to install this extension.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hiro-sun.vscode-emacs

But by clicking `install` button, it failed by unknown protocol of `vscode:`

The URI is `vscode:extension/hiro-sun.vscode-emacs`.

I think it works find if I use Windows. How can I install the extension in MacOS?

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac and Visual Studio Code are different products, so VSCode extension won't go to Visual Studio for Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That extension is for "VS Code". It will not work on "Visual Studio for Mac" or for regular "Visual Studio" on windows. These are all separate products